# If volatile fields are read directly from memory, where are non-volatile fields read from?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, volatile

I was recently reading volatile fields are thread-safe because

> When we use volatile keyword with a variable, all the threads read
>   its value directly from the memory and don’t cache it

So it got me to wonder, for non-volatile fields, where would the thread read its value from? I thought everything was stored in memory.

Comment: A register isn't directly "memory", so there are somethings that are not memory where a variable may be placed.

Comment: Could a non-volatile field (e.g. "private int x") be stored in a register?  If so, how is that determined?

Comment: Every `static` variable and every member variable has a _place_ in main memory, but each CPU in a multiprocessor system is allowed to keep its own local copy. That's the "cache" that answers below talk about. "Synchronizing" the caches of different CPUs in the system is expensive. Therefore the Java language does not do it except at special points where the programmer knows that a value changed by one thread will be needed in a different thread. When you declare a variable to be `volatile`, you are telling the compiler that you need every access to the variable to be synchronized.

Comment: Hi @Solomon, So I'm assuming that synchronizing the CPUs of different caches may be expensive, but isn't as expensive as accessing things directly from memory as one of the answers below implies?

Comment: https://blog.thesoftwarecraft.com/2014/07/javas-volatile-modifier.html may help

Comment: @Dave, In most multiprocessor architectures there is no such thing as "accessing things directly." _All_ accesses go through the cache.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)

Comment: @SolomonSlow Which CPU has such thing as un-synchronized cache and which asm instr do you use to sync it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement you quote is a misconception.
I recommend the following article: https://software.rajivprab.com/2018/04/29/myths-programmers-believe-about-cpu-caches/

> if volatile variables were truly written/read from main-memory every single time, they would be horrendously slow – main-memory references are 200x slower than L1 cache references. In reality, volatile-reads (in Java) can often be just as cheap as a L1 cache reference, putting to rest the notion that volatile forces reads/writes all the way to main memory. If you’ve been avoiding the use of volatiles because of performance concerns, you might have been a victim of the above misconceptions.

Comment: The above article seems to imply even volatile fields could be read from L1 caches.  Is that true?  Is that thread-safe?

Comment: @Dave, on a typical multi-processor system (not all harware platforms work in exactly the same way) _every_ memory access must go through a cache. Usually the platform has special instructions that can be used to "synchronize" caches belonging to different processors. One effect of `volatile` is, it forces the JVM to execute those special synchronization op codes every time the `volatile` variable is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Every thread has a Cache of the Main Memory.

> A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java Memory Model
>   ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable

For Example we have this static counter that is not Thread Safe

```
static int counter = 0;
```

If two threads reads and write this variable it will be like this

```
Main memory  - > static int counter 
T1-> Cache of the Main Memory. Reads/Writes directly from Cache
T2-> Cache of the Main Memory. Reads/Writes directly from Cache
```

So it will be inconsistent when reading and writing.

static  volatile  int counter = 0;

```
Main Memory - > static int counter;
T1 - > Read and Writes directly from the memory
T2 - > Read and Writes directly from the memory
```

I hope I give you a simple summary about this. Because you will need to check more about concurrency and [Atomic Access](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) for the concurrency of variables
Check more in the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)

Answer (score 0):

A core/thread on a processor can take a copy of a non `volatile` variable and place it in it's own cache (not main memory). This cached value gets updated but the main memory version does not until the thread deems it time to flush the value back.

In the event another core/thread tries to access the value from main memory, it may unknowingly find an out of date value.

The volatile modifier means that the variable data is kept up to date in main memory every time it changes and hence is always ready for when another thread needs to access/edit it.

Comment: Does the JVM have any control over where these variables get stored?  I thought these were instructions passed to the OS and then the OS decides where to store things.

Comment: From what I know, which is not much, I think the JVM tells the OS using native libraries that the variables are to be "volatile". The term varies at that level.

Comment: `are only periodically updated in main memory` could you provide more details about the period? what is the frequency?

Comment: A thread will take the data and store a local (cache) copy and manipulate that only. Once the thread is done with the variable, it will flush the updated value back to main memory. In this time, another thread may try to access the data, unknowingly finding it out of date. There is no fixed period that the value is updated from what I know.